# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find directory хотя она существует

Tags: python, база-данных, tensorflow

Пишу код распознавания болезни растений с картинки, все делаю по гайду и почему-то сам тенсор флоу пишет, что не может найти эту директорию, хотя можно спокойно через другую б

```
# Importing libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
# importing flower dataset
import pathlib
valid_dir=pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\Андрей\\Downloads\\New_Plant_Diseases_Dataset(Augmented)\\valid")
data_dir="C:\\Users\\Андрей\Downloads\\New_Plant_Diseases_Dataset(Augmented)\\train\\"
data_dir=pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
#grapehealthy = list(data_dir.glob('Grape___healthy/*'))
#print(grapehealthy[0])
#PIL.Image.open(str(grapehealthy[0]))
#print(image_count)
print(image_count)
# Training split
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32)
```

> 70295 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 24, in
>
> train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\image_dataset.py",
> line 213, in image_dataset_from_directory
> image_paths, labels, class_names = dataset_utils.index_directory(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\dataset_utils.py",
> line 542, in index_directory
> for subdir in sorted(tf.io.gfile.listdir(directory)):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
> line 768, in list_directory_v2
> raise errors.NotFoundError( tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find
> directory
> C:\Users\Андрей\Downloads\New_Plant_Diseases_Dataset(Augmented)\train

Answer (score 0):

Такая жк проблема, когда делал это в юпитере писал так - dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
dataset_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos.tar', origin=dataset_url, extract=True)
dataset_dir = pathlib.Path(dataset_dir).with_suffix('')
и это работало, а в пайчарме - нет

Comment: это у вас ответ или констатация «у меня такая же проблема»?

Answer (score 0):

У меня это починилось, когда убрал русские символы из пути к папке датасета, попробуй, может тоже решится